# Can we do SVD without computing eigenvector decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, singular-values

I'am studying SVD and PCA.(via Andrew Ng's coursera class)

I heard that using SVD for PCA is numerically more stable than doing eigenvector decomposition to covariance matrix.

From my knowledge so far, I have to do eigenvector decomposition to do SVD.

If he is not wrong, it seems that there is a way to calculate [U, sigma, V] without doing eigenvector decomposition to covariance matrix.

Is there a way? or is my understanding wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are stable ways to so it without computing the eigenvalue decomposition. See [here for a discussion](http://www.math.iit.edu/~fass/477577_Chapter_12.pdf).

You can also see discussions in [Trefethen & Bau](http://bookstore.siam.org/ot50/) as well as [Golub & van Loan](http://web.mit.edu/ehliu/Public/sclark/Golub%20G.H.,%20Van%20Loan%20C.F.-%20Matrix%20Computations.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The reference seems a bit too difficult for me. By the way, do you also have an answer about this question? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/314046/why-does-pca-do-svd-not-eig-to-covariance-matrix